# Error because of Prism : "System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mvvm, prism

I have a solution with four projects, as:

1. BridgeConcrete.BL
2. BridgeConcrete.DAL
3. BridgeConcrete.ViewModel
4. BridgeConcrete.WPF

I am using:

- Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Mvvm version 1.1.1.0
- Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Mvvm.Desktop version 1.1.1.0
- Microsoft.Practices.Prism.SharedInterfaces version 1.1.1.0

**BridgeConcrete.BL has nothing yet.**

**BridgeConcrete.DAL has:**

```
public class Project
{
    public Project()
    {
        AddedBy = 1;
        AddedDate = System.DateTime.Now;
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime AddedDate { get; set; }
    public int AddedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public int? ModifiedBy { get; set; }


    // Calculated Fields
    public int BridgeCount { get; private set; }
}
```

**BridgeConcrete.ViewModel has:**

```
public class ProjectViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private IEnumerable<Project> _projects;
    public IEnumerable<Project> Projects
    {
        get { return _projects; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _projects, value); }
    }

    private Project _selectedRecord;
    public Project SelectedRecord
    {
        get { return _selectedRecord; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _selectedRecord, value); }
    }

    public ProjectViewModel()
    {
        SelectedRecord = new Project() { Id = 1, Name = "Test 1" };
    }
}
```

**In BridgeConcrete.WPF, I have:**

1 . UserControl: ProjectView.xaml

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="BridgeConcrete.WPF.ProjectView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:BridgeConcrete.ViewModel;assembly=BridgeConcrete.ViewModel"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignWidth="299.257" Height="140.059">

    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <vm:ProjectViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>

    <Grid >
        <Label Content="Project ID:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,22,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="98,25,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="78" IsEnabled="False"                
                    Text="{Binding SelectedRecord.Id }"/>

        <Label Content="Project Name:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,48,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="99,53,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding SelectedRecord.Name}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="145" />
    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

2. MainWindow.xaml:

I call the User Control as:

```
<local:ProjectView Margin="0,0,0.4,5.4"/>
```

**The error is:**

System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'The method or operation is not implemented.'

Inner Exception

NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.

I do a lot of searching, but I couldn't find a solution, except that I have to debug. So, I did that, and I discover that problem is from Prism.

**When I removed the inheritance of Prism, it worked well.**

**Question:**

What is the problem here, how to solve this problem, please

Comment: The first thing you may want to try is upgrading to the latest version of [Prism](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism). 6.3 is available now.

Comment: I am using the newest version, what you are talking about is the old one.

Comment: The Microsoft.Practices.Prism namespace is no longer used in the latest version of Prism. The assemblies you list above give me the impression you are using an old version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably calling a virtual function that was intended for you to override. That method will throw the `NotImplementedException` (usually developers throw this exception in virtual methods they want people to implement, instead of making them `abstract`)

If you could attach the stack trace it might help point to the right direction.